# Using dictionary as parameter in matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

how can i use dictionary key or value in matplotlib instead of tuple

```
tuple=(1,2,3,4)
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, tuple, width, color='r')
```

but i want to do it like this

```
dic={'1':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4}
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, dic[key], width, color='r')
```

Comment: isn't dic.keys() what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, (dic[key] for key in dic.keys()), width, color='r')
```

Or even:

```
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, dic.values(), width, color='r')
```

based on Amars comment, if the dict is something like this:

```
dic={'a':(1,2),'b':(2,2),'c':(3,2)}
```

and you only want to use the values `(1, 2, 3)` you need to create an ordered set:

```
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, sorted(set(dic.values())), width, color='r')
```

Comment: There is no reason for the values to come out in a sensible order.

Comment: will u please tell me how to do it if have dictionary like this dic={'a':(1,2),'b':(2,2),'c':(3,2)} and i want to use only (1,2,3)

Answer (score 0):

I supect you want to do something like this

```
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, (dic[k] for k in ind), ...)
```

so that there is a mapping between your index and the values in your dictionary.